# How to update the value into a nested array of objects if value for specific key is same?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
let data = [
{"name":"Dhanush","createdAt":"2021/01/13 16:57:53","songs":[]},
{"name":"Dharma","createdAt":"2021/01/13 17:02:47","songs":[]},
{"name":"Sachin","createdAt":"2021/01/13 17:30:45","songs":[]}
]

let name = "Dhanush"

let song = {
  'id':1,
  'duration': '5 mins',
  'name': 'Bingo'
}
```

Here I need to loop the data array and check if data.name === name , if it s true I need to push the song object to the songs array inside the data.

this means

```
data = data.map(val => val.name === name ? val.songs = [...val.songs,song] : val.songs)
```

I tried like this. but it doesn't work.

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `data.songs` doesn't refer to anything, you want `val.songs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning `val` when using map method.

```js
let data = [
  { name: 'Dhanush', createdAt: '2021/01/13 16:57:53', songs: [] },
  { name: 'Dharma', createdAt: '2021/01/13 17:02:47', songs: [] },
  { name: 'Sachin', createdAt: '2021/01/13 17:30:45', songs: [] },
];

const name = 'Dhanush';

const song = {
  id: 1,
  duration: '5 mins',
  name: 'Bingo',
};
data = data.map(
  (val) => (
    val.name === name ? (val.songs = [...val.songs, song]) : val.songs, val
  )
);
console.log(data);
```